# Swift Package Manager not resolving

Tags: swift-package-manager

I'm currently trying to use Swift Package Manager on a Perfect Server Side Swift project but when I run `Swift package update` it never resolves. Using the verbose flag it seems to keep cycling through the same dependencies over and over again.

Where I think the issue started is I'm trying to create a custom package to import into my project. I'm trying to build the package in a way that I can import it into other projects going forward. The issue is that my package itself relies on one of the Perfect Dependencies. If I remove my custom package from the overall project package the dependencies download successfully. So I can only assume it's my package that has the problem.

The dependencies for my package look like this

```
let package = Package(
    name: "TestPackage",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "TestPackage",
            targets: ["TestPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTP.git", majorVersion: 3),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "TestPackage",
            dependencies: ["PerfectHTTP"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["TestPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

Then my package.swift file for my main project looks like this

```
let package = Package(
    name: "json_api",
    targets: [],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 3),
        .Package(url:"/local/path/to/TestPackage", majorVersion:0, minor:1),
    ]
)
```

As you can see they both import the Perfect-HTTP package (Perfect-HTTP-Server does this via

`.package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTP.git", from: "3.0.0"),`
)

When it hangs it keeps getting `Perfect-COpenSSL` and `Perfect-Thread` though rather than Perfect-HTTP

I'm pretty new to SPM and this is the first time I've tried created my own package. How should I go about trying to resolve what I can only assume is some kind of circular dependency issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I managed to resolve this and thought it might be useful for others.

I had made my version tag in git as 'v0.1' whereas I needed to give it full semantic versioning e.g 0.1.0 as the tag and that worked succesfully

Comment: How did you do that versioning? Can you show us full Package.swift file?

Comment: I want to emphasize `How should I go about trying to resolve what I can only assume is some kind of circular dependency issue?`. I occasionally have this kind of issue and don't have good tools to resolve the issue. It `seems` like the SPM ought to provide a little more help.

Comment: I just fixed my latest own instance of this problem. This is also occurring in a server-side Swift development context. In my case I was using Swift 5.0.1, and encountering these SPM resolution issues. After updating to Swift 5.2.3, the problem went away. I'm assuming relatively recent changes to improve how SPM resolves dependencies. Thanks Swift people! :).